# Can we use openJDK10 for ionic developement on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ionic-framework

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04. I have install jdk-10.0.1 and latest version of Android SDK. I have verify `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` variables are set to correct respective directories.

Still when i triggering below command 
`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

It gives me following error after lint operation

> ANDROID_HOME=/home/aby/Android/Sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=/home/aby/Java/jdk-10.0.1
>
> (node:7586) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
>       at /home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:370:19
>       at _fulfilled (/home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
>       at /home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
>       at runSingle (/home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (/home/aby/Projects/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>
> (node:7586) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside ofan async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:7586) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections thatare not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

What should I do to make it working? What may be the reason of this error or should I used JDK instead of OpenJDK?

Comment: I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959651/4826457

Comment: Yes @SurajRao !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As per official Cordova documentation it supports only JDK 1.8 not greater till the date (April 2018)**. Or there might be problem with version detection script within cordova.

[Cordova: Installing the requirements](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#installing-the-requirements)

So I configure my system for JDK 1.8

Later on i found this stackoverflow Reference:

1. [Cordova : Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148212/6112685)
2. [JDK Error on ionic cordova run android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956970/jdk-error-on-ionic-cordova-run-android/48959651#48959651)